# What would be the approximate weight of an Iron Man suit?

Tags: marvel, iron-man

Considering all the equipment mounted inside the suit, including the weight of the alloy used to manufacture the suit in the first place, what would be the approximate weight of a classic Iron Man suit?

Comment: MCU? Comics? Which version?

Comment: There are many versions of Iron Man's suit, many of which would weigh differently, you need a more specific suit in mind.

Comment: For example, the Hulk Buster almost certainly weighs a lot more then the early "briefcase suit" seen in the opening of Iron Man 2.

Comment: Never mind the briefcase suit; what about the nanotech suit that deploys from a pendant in *Avengers: Infinity War*? What's left, a massless suit of pure energy? :)

Comment: @chepner Energy has mass.

Comment: @JohnO Yeah, yeah. :)

Answer (score 21):

Even if we don't consider the most unusual suits (such as the [godkiller suit](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Godkiller_Armor), the [Galactus-buster suit](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Galactus-Buster_Armor_(Earth-30847)), the LEGO suits, hulk-busters etc.), there are still probably more than a hundred suits in the comic books alone, with different equipment and capabilities.

If you want a single, base number, though... [Marvel's site has some stats for Iron Man](http://marvel.com/characters/29/iron_man), including the following:

[image: Iron man stats]

> **Weight:** 225 lbs.; (in armor) 425 lbs.

So I would say that, in their current iteration in comic books, Tony Stark's armor suits have a base template weight of two hundred pounds. We can imagine that there will be some small variation depending on what he is packing for particular missions.

Comment: "Group Affiliations: AA"  Not very anonymous.